# How to return abstract object in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```cpp
namespace ns {
class EXPORT IQuery : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    [several virtual methods]
};
}

class QmlInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE ns::IQuery *query(const QString &query);
    …
};
```

Somewhere in source file I do

```cpp
root_context_->setContextProperty("interface", &qml_interface);
```

and in QML I call

```js
q = interface.query(sometext)
```

The output gives

```
qrc:resources/qml/MainComponent.qml:293: Error: Unknown method return type: ns::IQuery*
```

I tried several combinations of QML_ELEMENT, QML_ANONYMOUS, Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, qRegisterType() but so far I had no luck.

How can I return an abstract type in QML?

Comment: You probably cannot call "namespace::" for a namespace, is a reserved keyword in the C++. As for the question, please show how do you register the `IQuery` type. Also please provide the platform, Qt version

Comment: its just a placeholder. edited avoid confusion. as is I dont register it because everything i try fails. all platform should be supported, dev setup on macos. qt 6.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned you create the type, there is a question with regards to object ownership (is it Javascript or C++ managed?) and whether the object needs to be a QObject. If the class being returned is nothing more than a struct, and you control the entire lifecycle through C++, then, Q_GADGET may be more appropriate.

If you return an object to which the QML side is free to copy and hold and there are multiple instances of, then, yeah, the object property should be a QObject with the object ownership set to Javascript. Hence, you are handling it over to the QML/JS engine and it's garbage collector to take care of. In that case, qmlRegisterType/qmlRegisterUncreatableType should work for you.